# UserAgents - разные заголовки

Tags: c#, httpclient

Вот запросы из разных браузеров и на один и тот же адрес у них есть какие то свои заголовки, которых нет у других.

Вот как понять / найти, не имея установленных всех браузеров разных стабильных версий, какие они свои заголовки отправляют ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это бессмысленная задача на "перепись населения". Есть заголовки без которых никак - их немного и их и надо обрабатывать. А любые вам нафига? Они не на что не влияют. Тем более не браузерами едиными - бывают ещё роботы, туда каких только приколов не пишут. Так что ещё раз -- давайте проговорим задачу. Для чего вам знать все возможные варианты заголовков? Также хорошо описать - вы по какую сторону баррикад работаете, на стороне клиента или на стороне сервера?

Comment: @AK хочу эмулировать делать запросы из под разных юзер-агентов, соответственно хочу быть похожим на них. Не хочется чтобы админ увидел что user-agent / IP разные, а запросы одинаковые - Как то так

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше бы вы предоставили нам самодостаточный, минимальный пример, с конкретным адресом, чтоб мы могли его проанализировать. Сейчас вы тычете пальцем в небо, задавая бессмысленные как для вас, так и для SO вопросы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ посмотрите свою почту, я писал xD. Всё что я хочу получить от этого адреса, я уже получил. Но задача на будущее не только получать что хочешь, но и быть точь в точь похожим за разные user-agents

Comment: Ну если вы хотите набор юнит-тестов для строго определённых параметров - то либо читать документацию (и наверняка весьма глубоко спрятанную, какие версии ПО какие протоколы как поддерживают - типа changelog'и внутренние документы) либо зафиксировать набор браузеров - и да, проводить натурные эксперименты. И не забудьте учесть таких маньяков как я, которые ставят хитрые плагины на свои браузеры, которые весьма изощрённо порой заголовки подменяют. Я не вижу других вариантов ответа.

Comment: @AK а, ну вот то что и хотел понять. Думал может базка какая то все общеизвестная  есть. Просто с юзер-агентами есть, а их запросами нет( Ну ладно, понял) Буду натур тесты если что проводить xD

Comment: @Vipz Я сейчас не конкретно про этот вопрос (хотя он тоже), а про все последние ваши, где вы сначала хотите отрубить у селениума все, за что его так полюбил народ (спрашивается, зачем тогда селениум?), затем вы вдруг решили подкинуть заголовки, которые совсем не относятся каким либо образом к работе запросов, потом вовсе решили играться с версиями HTTP, ну и теперь на тебе, играемся с UserAgent, в попытках обмануть систему... Я не знаю, но как по мне, все эти ваши действия бесмысленны. А по поводу почты, если через форму на сайте писали, то она не работает, можете напрямую написать (но зачем?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Долго общался с сайтом по Post запросам и вдруг в самый необходимый момент запросы перестали проходить, тех скудных знаний которые имел по запросам в тот момент, не хватило чтобы проанализировать что изменилось и снова начать общаться. А так как имел опыт использования Selenium, прибегнул к Selenium чтобы отправлять форму, а прокси кушали трафик вот и хотел всё лишнее отключить xD На Gmail отписался.

Comment: Не имеет никакого смысла коллекционировать агентов, берите первый попавшийся, с которым все работает и используйте.

Comment: @aepot Если я буду постоянно с одним юзер агентом - мне будут перекрывать кислород( Никому не понравится 10ки тысяч запросов с одного юзер-агента, одинаковыми заголовками и только разными IP. Или я заблуждаюсь...

Comment: @Vipz откруда вы знаете, что не будут, если вы будете использовать разные заголовки? Отличить маскирующийся парсер от реального браузера можно даже по порядку заголовков в запросе, по генерации bound кода в form/multipart и еще много по чему. Но защита от парсеров на основе HTTP заголовков не эффективна, потому что если автор парсера не менее грамотный, чем админ сервера, он замаскируется так, что байт в байт не отличишь запрос от реального браузера (чего вы собственно и пытаетесь добиться). Поэтому для надежной защиты от ботов используются совершенно другие способы защиты.

Comment: @aepot а я не знаю ничего) Я методом проб и ошибок. Вот сначала решил разобраться с заголовками. А какие другие способы ? это цифровые отпечатки в Cookie? Типа тех что сайт f.vision показывает ?

Comment: Есть сайты, выполняющие специальный код в браузере, который проверяет на то что это настоящий браузер или нет, и даже есть те, которые проверяют, является ли браузер в данный момент под управлением селениума. Из этой проверки высчитывается специальный ключ и кладется в куку. Взломать конечно и такую защиту можно, но сложность взлома максимально высокая.

Comment: @aepot ну а при Get запросе же можно эмулировать браузер ? Брать эту сгенерированную куку и отправлять уже POST. Не так это работает ?

Comment: @aepot а по поводу палева селениума - в firefox driver отключается одной настройкой вроде.

Comment: Это вечная война: вирусы против антивирусов, боты простив антиботов, парсеры против антипарсеров. Она никогда не закончится.

Comment: @aepot зато занятно xD